# Load custom data from HTTP web page

Tags: java, android, http

I need to read some specific data in an HTML web page, from Android.

I wrote class that build the exact HTTP address. Now I can load the page and parse the data I want, but since bandwidth is expensive on smartphones, I would like to load just some custom data off the HTTP web page, to save memory.

Is this possible? How could I do it?

Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternatives are

1. Build a Proxy and host it on your server, which will parse the web page, and return relative data to the smart phones.
2. <strike>Read the response stream and once you get all the data you need stop reading. this is depended on how large the page is and where the relevant text you need is located.</strike>

Comment: It's not possible to stop reading. The connection will get stale and you might run out of them sooner or later. The HTTP response needs to be consumed to EOF in any way. You could just not store it in memory anymore after reading the desired part (i.e. do not assign to some variable).

Comment: @balusc If you are reading the http trough a TCP stream, why is it not possible to stop reading?

Comment: In Android you normally use `HttpClient` for this to minimize the verbosity.

Comment: but will this method load also the Images? Not loading them could save me a lot of memory....

Comment: @muaddib Why would it load the images? are you **not** using a `HttpClient` to scrape the web page?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister , Thank you for your advice. I wasn't understanding exactly how HttpClient worked. Now I solved it.  :)